# Image Click Event

Tags: jquery

In my program I used image pop up window.  some what images scrolling in home page.

While I click on the image in the sense the pop up will open and show the particular image in popup windows. How I can show the image in pop up window. Now I got the pop up window but I can't show the image in the popup window.

Here is my code so far:

```
$("img").click(function(){
     var $dialog = $('<div></div>') 
         .html(' <img src="localhost:81/keprandemo/media/catalog/product/cache/1/…; width="200" height="200" alt="Milk(1 lit)">') 
         .dialog({ autoOpen: true, resizable: false, draggable: false, width: 600, height:600, modal: true, title: 'Create Your Own PopUp Window' }); });
```

Comment: You should pass the img src to pop window.

Comment: without code nobody can help you

Comment: Show some code and a jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: $("img").click(function(){ 

      var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
   
            .html('   <img src="http://localhost:81/keprandemo/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/170x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/o/download.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Milk(1 lit)">')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                width: 600,
    height:600,
                modal: true,
                title: 'Create Your Own PopUp Window'
            });
     });
    </script>

Comment: i pass the img src directly but i want dynamically. which image i choose that image url i want to get and display in jquery

Comment: @user2893238 make jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
var ImageSource="";
$('.yourImageClass').click(function(){
     ImageSource=$(this).attr('src');
});
```

//Pass this ImageSource to your image window

**EDIT:**

```
$("img").click(function(){
    var source=$(this).attr('src');
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>') 
         .html('<img src="'+source+'" width="200" height="200" alt="Milk(1 lit)">') 
         .dialog({ autoOpen: true, resizable: false, draggable: false, width: 600, height:600, modal: true, title: 'Create Your Own PopUp Window' }); 
});
```

This code should do the trick.!

Comment: but i have 10 images each image id is same.

Comment: You are going against the rule of HTML.. A page should have unique element ID's.

Comment: you have to fetch the elements by class, not by ID. Assign the same class "yourImageClass" to every element and run the above code

Comment: another one problem.  <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170) ?>" width="151" height="140" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />                                                     
                                                  
                                                      <span class="productname">

<!-- kepran changes removed product redirect url -->
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($_product->getUrlPath())?>" >  <?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>      
  
 
  </span>

Comment: if once i click the image i get the image source. at the same time i want to get the image name and the price

Comment: how i can get it please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("img").click(function(){
 var $dialog = $('<div id="urID"></div>') 
     .dialog({ autoOpen: true, resizable: false, draggable: false, width: 600, height:600, modal: true, title: 'Create Your Own PopUp Window' });
   //ur div id name.
   $('#urID').html('<img src="localhost:81/keprandemo/media/catalog/product/cache/1/…; width="200" height="200" alt="Milk(1 lit)">');
  });
```